# Finding lat and long returning 0,0

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, google-maps, geolocation

I am using Google to take an address to get its lat and long. I run through about 60-65 address. Each time though I will randomly get 5 or 6 that return a 0,0 coordinate pair.

Every time the indexes that fail are different so I am sure that it is not an address problem.

Here is the code that I am using to return the lat and long

Would it possibly be that I am calling this method from inside a for loop? Maybe calling it over and over so fast will cause it to hick-up sometimes?

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)addressLocation:(NSString*)_address city:(NSString*)_city state:(NSString*)_state {
    NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@", _address, _city, _state];
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", [temp stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSString *locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString ] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

    NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    double latitude = 0.0;
    double longitude = 0.0;

    if([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]) {
        latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);;
    }

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
    location.latitude = latitude;
    location.longitude = longitude;

    return location;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have found a work around for the moment if anyone else if having trouble with this.

I go through my list once finding the lat and long of each address.

If there is an error returned from the Google query I add that address to a holding array. *Meaning that I passed the rate limit mentioned by Firoze.*

After the initial run through is done, I go through the holding array and find the locations of each address.

I am sure that there is a much more cleaner implementation of this but for anyone who is not able to obtain a business license this is a hacked way around.

I hope this helps,
Cory

Comment: Google has strict restrictions on how this service can be used and are constantly updating their algorithm to detect abuse and temporarily (or permanently) block access to it. You can try to slow your system down, but that may stop working tomorrow. Perhaps you are not using the service for it's intended purpose, and should find some other address lookup service.

Comment: A suggestion for what changes to make? Perhaps detect you've been rate limited and then wait a few seconds before continuing to do the lookup. Or if you mean a suggested alternative service, perhaps the "Google Maps API For Business" service is perfect for you. Or you could download the openstreetmap.org database to your own server, and perform your own geocoding.

Comment: Would you suggest Yahoo map services? I feel that Google is a bit more stable.

Comment: I think Yahoo and the *free* Google maps services are both unreliable. They're big money pits (map data is very expensive). Both companies could (and regularly do) change or remove features from the free service. If you want reliable you really need to be paying for the data, or use openstreetmap.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check to see if locationString is nil. And if so, look at the error. My guess is that your calls are being rate limited.

You should probably look at Google's terms of service for this service.

Comment: I believe that they are being rate limited is there anyway around this? I have a list of address and I need to determine which is closest to me. I don't see any other way to find their location coordinates to determine distance.

Comment: Well, it depends on what your application does. This is more of business question than a technical one. I'm sure Google can help you determine what license/agreement you need for your particular use case. Check the forums here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/premier/

Comment: I looked at it but I'm afraid that $17,000 for a business license is out of budget. Do you have any suggestions on other services Firoze?

Comment: Well, you're assuming you even need a business license. Not all apps do, but those guys are really helpful as far as helping you figure it out. They know all their terms and conditions better than anyone here will. We use Google, so I can't comment on other services. Perhaps someone else here can. But again, you're not really asking a programming question now.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am waiting to hear from them. Hopefully we will be able to work something out.